# How to pre populate a node add form with multiple field collection items?

Tags: entities

How to pre populate a field collection field with multiple values?

I have a node type with a field collection field which has four fields and cardinality is set to unlimited.

In my custom module I implement hook_form_alter and assign default values to the collection inside a loop, but it displays only one field collection. I tried to set the cardinality of the field collection field to the number of items I want, but failed as I can't find a way to set the cardinality programmatically.

Comment: I already answered this question [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30586/how-to-pre-populate-multiple-field-collection-fields-in-node-form/39351#39351). Have a look.