# how to show 2 content fields when page load in drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, entities

I am using drupal 7 and I have created a content type and give the ability to this content type, User can show this content type and create node..Here I am using field collection with 2 fields textarea and image upload with multiple option..So basically its show one group or textarea and image. but I need to show 4 groups in first time..Then user click on other item then it create new group.[image]

Comment: Very tough English.. I knew your trouble, see this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30586/how-to-pre-populate-multiple-field-collection-fields-in-node-form/39351#39351

Comment: Its not helping me.  i need by default 4 groups of above image..when I go to create node.

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit complex for me. But, all you have to do is **increment items count and rebuild the form** as does here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.form.inc/function/field_add_more_submit/7